Why do pdfs on my desktop named with just numbers show generic pdf icon, others show preview?
I currently have three pdfs on my desktop. Two of them have names that include numbers and letters. They show the preview of the file. My third pdf's name uses all numbers and it just shows the generic pdf icon. If I move that file to another location, it shows the preview, but on my desktop, it's just the pdf icon. Any idea why?
It's not a huge deal, just kinda bugs me. TIA
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Does your computer have a graphics card? Maybe your graphics card is going bad, so it occasionally fails to render thumbnail images.
